# Bash: get substring after a dot character, compare

Tags: string, bash, compare

I have:

```
string1="start1.MATCH.ext"
string2="start2.qwer.ext"
string3="start3.MATCH.ext"
```

...

I want to take every string and extract the portion after the first period, so

```
MATCH.ext
qwer.ext
MATCH.ext
```

And then compare these substrings such that I can do something in an if-statement if they match:

```
if (substr[i] == substr[j]) //now I can do something with string1 and string3
```

How can I do this in Bash? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chop the front of a string using `${var#*.}`, and compare with `if [[ ... ]]`:

```
string1="start1.MATCH.ext"
string2="start2.qwer.ext"
string3="start3.MATCH.ext"

if [[ ${string1#*.} = ${string3#*.} ]]; then
        echo They match
else
        echo No match
fi
```